# Call web API with string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use Python for my own tracking project. I am trying to put in MySQL for PHP latitude and longitude.

Only something is wrong with me for `wget`.

The script works well only it does not put longitudes and latitude well, I think it is because of it.

```
import serial
import time
import string
import pynmea2
import os
import os.path

while True:
        port="/dev/ttyAMA0"
        ser=serial.Serial(port, baudrate=9600, timeout=0.5)
        dataout = pynmea2.NMEAStreamReader()
        newdata=ser.readline()

        if newdata[0:6] == "$GPRMC":
                newmsg=pynmea2.parse(newdata)
                lat=newmsg.latitude
                lng=newmsg.longitude
                gps = "Latitude=" + str(lat) + "and Longitude=" + str(lng)
                print(gps)
                os.system('sudo wget -qO- https://appnsetsd.devss/empleado/insert-gps.php?usuario=liviudiaconu&lat=' + str(lat) + '&long=' + str(lng))
```

I put echo instead of wget to see how it has the address.
it doesn't seem to match the strings with the url.

```
os.system('sudo echo https://appnaeatwd.dedv/empleado/insert-gps.php?usuario=liviudiaconu&lat=' + str(lat) + '&long='+str(lng))
```

and answer

```
 Latitude=40.3156173333and Longitude=-3.482346
https://appnetdw.devwd/empleado/insert-gps.php?usuario=liviudiaconu
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got the right URL? When I tried to go to the url I was told that the server was not found

Comment: `os.system` does not provide any output, just exit codes. You might want to use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) ?

Comment: what does not place well are these  &lat=' + str(lat) + '&long=' + str(lng)) . does not send them empty